# Populating JSON Array/Object

Tags: jquery, json

I've some JSON data below,

```
{
    "cleaning" : [
        {
            "MOPS" : [
                {
                    "id"    : "123",
                    "name"  : "best mops",
                    "price" : "123"
                },
                {
                    "id"    : "123",
                    "name"  : "best mops",
                    "price" : "123"
                },
                {
                    "id"    : "123",
                    "name"  : "best mops",
                    "price" : "123"
                }
            ],

            "GlOVES" : [
                {
                    "id"    : "123",
                    "name"  : "best mops",
                    "price" : "123"
                },
                {
                    "id"    : "123",
                    "name"  : "best mops",
                    "price" : "123"
                },
                {
                    "id"    : "123",
                    "name"  : "best mops",
                    "price" : "123"
                }
            ],

            "Another Items" : [
                {
                    "id"    : "123",
                    "name"  : "best mops",
                    "price" : "123"
                },
                {
                    "id"    : "123",
                    "name"  : "best mops",
                    "price" : "123"
                },
                {
                    "id"    : "123",
                    "name"  : "best mops",
                    "price" : "123"
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

now I need a help in populated this data in desired format showing in the below image.

[image]

The JSON object or array is valid but I'm finding it very difficult to populate the data it has. If my JSON data wants modifications or the data can be simplified plz make it for me. Moreover, I want just to loop through the JSON data and show the result on the web page using jQuery.

Comment: You've got the pseudo logic down, make an attempt at a solution. You know you have to loop the above structure - so start with that!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "cleaning" : [
    {
      "MOPS" : [
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        }
      ],

      "GlOVES" : [
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        }
      ],

      "Another Items" : [
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var result = $('#result');
var obj = data.cleaning[0];
for (var index in obj) {
  var cat = $('<div class="cat"><h2>' + index + '</h2></div>').appendTo(result);
  var items = obj[index];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('<div>' + items[i].name + '</div>').appendTo(cat);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align:center;  
}

h2 {
  margin:0;  
}

.cat {
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you need to try do it by yourself even though I answer this. In the future, please follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

```js
var data = {
  "cleaning" : [
    {
      "MOPS" : [
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        }
      ],

      "GlOVES" : [
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        }
      ],

      "Another Items" : [
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        },
        {
          "id"    : "123",
          "name"  : "best mops",
          "price" : "123"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var result = $('#result');
var obj = data.cleaning[0];
for (var index in obj) {
  var cat = $('<div class="cat"><h2>' + index + '</h2></div>').appendTo(result);
  var items = obj[index];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('<div>' + items[i].name + '</div>').appendTo(cat);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align:center;  
}

h2 {
  margin:0;  
}

.cat {
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/mutela/edit?html,js

Comment: I glad to hear. If so, please accept the answer so it will help to other people. (You can upvote too :-) )